# Incomplete image using usb camera

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to capture single images using opencv, but the images seem to be incomplete as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwFg9.png)

I would appreciate if some one explains me the reason to this problem!

Installed is one **USB** camera (**IMX179**) on a **raspberry pi**(server) USB port. **This port is shared on my notebook** (client) due to **SSH** connection.

So the **raspberry pi** is used as usb server only, I am planning to use two other ports to use other usb cameras for single images that should be taken at the same time.

I simply use the following code to make my images:

```
import cv2

p1= "/dev/v4l/by-path/platform-vhci_hcd.0-usb-0:1:1.0-video-index0"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(p1)
frame = cap.read()[1]
cv2.imwrite('image_1.png', frame)
```

Comment: Are yo using an USB **3** port? if not that might be a proble. can you modify the camera's FPS? if yes try decreasing it

Comment: Yes IVan! I am using USB 2, which is surely slower, but I think fast enough to transfer a 5 MP image. Anyways, I will try to reduce the FPS and check it.  I will also try to use Raspberry Pi 4 with 8 GB RAM instead of the older pi 3 one. Others said that the first frame is sometime incomplete in some systems. I will also try to capture two frames in series and see if the second frame is better. I will submit my Feedback over the Weekend.

Comment: USB 2.0 transfer speed is 480 megabits per second (Mbps), while USB 3.0 transfer speed is 4,800 Mbps => if your image is 5Mb (grayscale)  you can't go over 12FPS (and divide it by 3 if it's a colored image)

Comment: You image is colored, so,  you are probably transmiting 3 channels => USB 2.0 might be a bottleNeck

Comment: In this case the, I will have to buy other cameras with USB 3.0 interface. The problem is that, the rapberry pi has only two USB 3.0 ports. And I have to use three camereas at least, may be I will have to use even 4 for my project.